# Encrypt django model field using python 3.5

Tags: django, python-3.x, encryption, django-models

I want one of my django model field to be encrypted. I found some extensions such as `django-encrypted-fields` and `django_extensions`, but both of them are using `keyzcar` which is for python 2.7 and I do my project with python 3.5.
Can you guys suggest easy way to do django field encryption under 3.5 version of python?

Answer (score 5):

Solved the problem with `django-fernet-fields` extension. Works well, it uses SECRET_KEY from django settings. Also you can specify custom encryption key.
Here is a [web page](http://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 4):

I tried @Михаил Павлов solution by installing `django-fernet-fields` but it doesn't work on Django 3+ versions. My workaraound was to create a custom model that extends default `CharField` and uses Fernet native lib for encryption under the hood:

```
import base64

from django.db.models import CharField
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from core import settings


class SecureString(CharField):
    """Custom Encrypted Field"""

    salt = bytes(settings.SECURE_STRING_SALT, encoding="raw_unicode_escape")
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), 
                     length=32, 
                     salt=salt, 
                     iterations=100000, 
                     backend=default_backend())

    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(settings.SECRET_KEY.encode('utf-8')))
    f = Fernet(key)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        return str(self.f.decrypt(value), encoding="raw_unicode_escape")

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return self.f.encrypt(bytes(value, encoding="raw_unicode_escape"))
```

Comment: I had to parse to bytes before saving and parse back to string when reading. I'm using Django v3.2.3 / Cryptography v3.4.7

Comment: No module named core?

Comment: tried to make https://pypi.org/project/django-fernet-encrypted-fields/